# map doesn't displayed after signing with older play store certificate

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

When i run the application from eclipse it runs perfectly but when i sign the a application with the older play store certificate and then installing the apk on device map doesn't work it shows blank page..

Comment: You need a new API key with older certificate

Comment: Go to google map api site where you can follow the process

Comment: i have signed the app twice new api key that works perfectly but the same problem if the signing with older certificate has something different process so pls send me an appropriate link for that

Comment: https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make new key for your app in command line write this command  `-keytool.exe -v -list - exportcert -alias aliasname - keystore "keystore path"`